# A needless JAXB class?

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have a simple XML file

```
<servers>  
<server>  
<id>Server0</id>  
</server>  
<server>  
<id>Server1</id>  
</server>  
<server>  
<id>Server2</id>  
</server>  
<server>  
<id>Server3</id>  
</server>  
<servers>
```

I have two JAXB classes. One for Servers and one for Server. The Servers one is simply a wrapper and does nothing else. Anyway I could ditch it? I would need to make the Server class smart enough.  Currently it is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
@XmlRootElement(name = "server")  
public class JAXBServer {  
    protected String id;  

    public String getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
}
```

And requires the Servers class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard JAXB APIs your `Servers` class is required.  If you are implementing something like a JAX-RS service however you can use a `List<Server>` and a wrapper element will automatically be added for you.